# Django! Не могу сделать фильтрацию в таблице-связке User_Ad

Tags: mysql, python, django, сервер, orm

Есть таблица `User` и `Ad`. Они связаны отношением `ManyToMany`. В следствии этой связи, `Django` создал для них таблицу `User_Ad`, в которую я записываю "подписку" **пользователя (`User`)** на **заявку (`Ad`)**. Т.е. эта связать между определенным пользователем и определенной заявкой записывается в таблицу `User_Ad`. В таблице `User` есть поле `adPk`. С его помощью я могу записать определенного пользователя на определенную заявку, все это будет записываться в `User_Ad` в виде: `id_user` - `id_ad`

**Мне нужно:**
По полю `driver`, которое в `Ad`, получить всех "подписчиков" этой заявки (`Ad`).

P.S. Не думайте над тем, как я получаю `drive`. Он у меня уже есть.

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Заявка'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    timeStart = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    timeEnd = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    cityStart = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    cityEnd = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=False)
    driver = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)


class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Пользователь'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    serName = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    adPk = models.ManyToManyField(Ad)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Django! Не знаю как сделать фильтрацию в таблицах ManyToMany](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469925/django-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%85-manytomany)

Comment: Перефразировал вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй:

```
User.objects.filter(adPk__driver=driver)
```

Подробнее в [оф доке](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).